# Which practice is better when throwing an exception in a service?

Tags: java, spring, api, rest

I'm working on a Spring Boot CRUD RESTful API and i'm trying to define the best way of doing certain things, for instance :

This is my *List user by its id* endpoint service :

```
@Service
public class DetailUserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

    public Optional<User> listUser(Long id) {

        Optional<User> user = repository.findById(id);
        if (!user.isPresent()) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException(id);
        } else {
            return repository.findById(id);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is another way of writing it :

```
@Service
public class DetailUserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

    public User listUser(Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(id));
    }
}
```

Both ways work but how do i know which is better?

Comment: you're querying the repository twice in the first snippet. which makes it the worse of the two. For both snippets returning a 404 Not found would also be good design

Answer (score -2):

Using `java-8` is always a better choice for less code and more readable code.
You can use below tyle of as you mentioned it as your second option.
Using the `Optional.orElseThrow()` method represents another elegant alternative to the `isPresent()-get()` pair

You can find out more here
https://dzone.com/articles/using-optional-correctly-is-not-optional

```
@Service
public class DetailUserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

    public User listUser(Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(id));
    }
}
```